# Javascript - Invoking a function if there is a fragment in the url

Tags: javascript

I have a carousel with various magazines and on click on each of the magazines in the carousel, I scroll down on the page to the section where I show the details of the magazine that was clicked. I pass the magazine details and create the elements according to the passed values. 
This is the html:

```
        @foreach($issues as $issue)
          <div class="swiper-slide magazine-image">
            <div
              class="slider-image-wrap js-magazine-selector"
              data-id='{{ $issue->first()->magazine->id }}'
              data-name='{{ $issue->first()->magazine->name }}'
              data-summary='{{ $issue->first()->magazine->summary ?: '' }}'
              data-magazine-image='{{ $issue->first()->magazine->image ?: '' }}'
              data-issue-image='{{ $issue->first()->image  }}'
            >
              <img src="/imagecache/medium/{{ $issue->first()->image  }}">
              <div class="magazine-overlay">
                <div>
                  <p>{{ $issue->first()->magazine->name }}</p>
                  <a href="#">Se magasinet</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        @endforeach
```

So, then on click I call the function that calls the function that creates magazine details section:

```
$(function() {
  $('.js-magazine-selector').click(function(){
    var img = $(this),
        id = img.data('id'),
        name = img.data('name'),
        summary = img.data('summary'),
        magazineImage = img.data('magazine-image'),
        issueImage = img.data('issue-image'),
        page = img.data('page');

    $('#back').addClass('not-allowed');
    $('#forward').removeClass('not-allowed');

    showMagazineDetail(id, name, summary, magazineImage, issueImage, page);

  });
});
```

And this is the function that creates magazine details section:

```
var showMagazineDetail = function showMagazineDetail(id, name, summary, issueImage, magazineImage, page){
    images = [];
    nextImage = 0;
    imagesIndex = 0;
    loadedImages = [];
    scrollPoint = document.height;

    window.location.hash = name;
    $(".magazine-section").css('visibility', 'visible');

    $('#name').text(name);
    $('#summary').text(summary);
    $('#cover-image').attr({"src" : '/imagecache/cover/' + magazineImage, "alt" : name});

    if (issueImage != '') {
      $('#issueImage').show();
      $('#issueImage').attr({"src" : '/imagecache/medium/' + issueImage, "alt" : name});
    }else {
      $('#issueImage').hide();
      $('#issueImage').attr({"src" : '', "alt" : name});
    }

    // $('body').css('overflow-y', 'scroll');

    $('html,body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(".magazine-detail").offset().top - 80
    });

    $.getJSON("issue/images",
        { id: id },
        function(result){
          if (result.length < 2){
              $('.magazine-preview-nav').hide();
          } else {
              $('.magazine-preview-nav').show();
          }
          $.each(result, function(i, value){
              images.push(value);
          });
          preload();
    });
};
```

That works fine, but I need to add a feature that when a user passes the url with the hash fragment of the magazine name, that it invokes the function same as it would on clicking the magazine in the carousel. I just don't know how to pass other parameters that are needed for creating the magazine detail section, so I was thinking of creating a function where if there is a hash fragment on page load to find the element in the carousel with the same name as the one in the hash fragment and then execute the click function on it, but not sure how to do that, and if that is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, on function ready, get the hash, select an element and then call the function like you said:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var name = window.location.hash.substr(1);

  if (name != '') {
    var selectedMagazine = $('[data-name="' + name + '"]'),
        id = selectedMagazine.data('id'),
        name = selectedMagazine.data('name'),
        summary = selectedMagazine.data('summary'),
        magazineImage = selectedMagazine.data('magazine-image'),
        issueImage = selectedMagazine.data('issue-image'),
        page = selectedMagazine.data('page');

    showMagazineDetail(id, slug, name, summary, magazineImage, issueImage, page);
  }
});
```

If there is any more efficient way of doing it I am not sure, but this will do the job for what you asked for.